# Convert dbeaver create table script into sql server script

Tags: dbeaver

I have to migrate some table from Database informix (i'm using dbeaver for it) to Sql server.
When i click on table to create DDL script , it's different script than sql server create table script.

Does anyone know the hack that how we can generate sql server create table script from dbeaver tables.

Thanks